# Instruction would span across PC

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I use arm-gcc to compile the code for cortext-m4, but the code will crash when enter the function

```
   char buf[20];
   sprintf(buf, "%d",1);
```

I use lauterbach Trace32 to debug the code, before enter the "sprintf" function it is:

```
    E92D000E  siprintf:             push    {r1-r3}
    E3E03102                        mvn     r3,#-0x80000000   ; r3,#-2147483648
    E52DE004                        push    {r14}
    E24DD070                        sub     r13,r13,#0x70    ; r13,r13,#112
    E58D0008                        str     r0,[r13,#0x8]
    E58D0018                        str     r0,[r13,#0x18]
    E58D301C                        str     r3,[r13,#0x1C]
    E58D3010                        str     r3,[r13,#0x10]
    E59F0038                        ldr     r0,0xE628
    E59F3038                        ldr     r3,0xE62C
    E59D2074                        ldr     r2,[r13,#0x74]
    E58D3014                        str     r3,[r13,#0x14]
    E28D1008                        add     r1,r13,#0x8      ; r1,r13,#8
    E28D3078                        add     r3,r13,#0x78     ; r3,r13,#120
    E5900000                        ldr     r0,[r0]
    E58D3004                        str     r3,[r13,#0x4]
    EB0000B2                        bl      0xE8D8           ; _svfiprintf_r
    E3A02000                        mov     r2,#0x0          ; r2,#0
    E59D3008                        ldr     r3,[r13,#0x8]
```

but when it enter the function it change to:

```
    000E      siprintf:             ////////                 ; **instruction would span across PC**
    E92D                            align   0xE92D
    E3E03102                        mvn     r3,#-0x80000000   ; r3,#-2147483648
    E52DE004                        push    {r14}
    E24DD070                        sub     r13,r13,#0x70    ; r13,r13,#112
    E58D0008                        str     r0,[r13,#0x8]
    E58D0018                        str     r0,[r13,#0x18]
    E58D301C                        str     r3,[r13,#0x1C]
    E58D3010                        str     r3,[r13,#0x10]
    E59F0038                        ldr     r0,0xE628
    E59F3038                        ldr     r3,0xE62C
    E59D2074                        ldr     r2,[r13,#0x74]
    E58D3014                        str     r3,[r13,#0x14]
    E28D1008                        add     r1,r13,#0x8      ; r1,r13,#8
    E28D3078                        add     r3,r13,#0x78     ; r3,r13,#120
    E5900000                        ldr     r0,[r0]
    E58D3004                        str     r3,[r13,#0x4]
    EB0000B2                        bl      0xE8D8           ; _svfiprintf_r
    E3A02000                        mov     r2,#0x0          ; r2,#0
    E59D3008                        ldr     r3,[r13,#0x8]
```

which complier option or link option I should use to avoid this problem?

Comment: What does "span across PC" mean? What exactly are you trying to show with that assembly? Please describe it explicitly rather than assuming people can automatically understand what you are trying to highlight .

Comment: Sorry, I also don't know "span across PC" mean? It display on debug view when the code run into function "sprintf",  
```
    000E      siprintf:             ////////                 ; instruction would span across PC
```

Comment: You are possibly jumping to an incorrect conclusion. Instead of showing what you think may be the problem you need to provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that has the crash. May be it has nothing to do with that assembly. But we can't help you unless you provide the code needed for us to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]". -- "span across PC" seems to mean that the PC is set "in the middle" of an instruction as the debugger sees it. -- Please tell us the address of `siprint()` and show us the code that jumps to it. Is this ARM or Thumb code? [Edit] your question to add this information, don't post a comment.

Comment: if those are the instructions on the left, not a single one of those will run on an cortex-m

Comment: what does the toolchain disassembler show (not a debugger).

Comment: provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem including your complete, minimal, command line used for the toolchain tools that build the example.

Comment: looks like you are linking in the wrong C library (one would have of course ask why using a C library on a microcontroller, are you using an RTOS?  which one?)